# WPF TabControl cannot switch tabs when hosting DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

In the default `TabControl` you can switch tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, however if one of the tabs contain `DataGrid` it all breaks. For example, if I had a simple `TabControl` containing nothing but TextBoxes:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <TextBox/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <TextBox/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Tab3">
        <TextBox/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And repeatedly pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, current Tab would cycle:

> Tab1 > Tab2 > Tab3 > Tab1 > ...etc

but if I were to put virtually any `DataGrid` in one of the middle Tabs, for example:

```
...    
<TabItem Header="Tab2"> <!--replacing 2nd tab content-->
    <TabItem.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="Items" Type="{x:Type Run}">
            <Run Text="Foo"/>
            <Run Text="Bar"/>
            <Run Text="Baz"/>
        </x:Array>
    </TabItem.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource Items}"/>
</TabItem>
```

the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> would get stuck not being able to ever get past said Tab:

> Tab1 > Tab2 > Tab1 > Tab2 > ...etc

How can I fix the issue?

---

I have tried `IsTabStop="False"` on the `DataGrid` and several combinations of `KeyBoardNavigation` properties, all of those had either no effect or were contraproductive.

---

**Edit(2):** the issue seems to appear mainly when the `DataGrid` is the *first* focusable child of `TabItem`, for example content:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource Items}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

*almost* works, until user selects the `DataGrid`. If the grid is selected next <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> goes back to first Tab rather than to the next one.

Comment: Not sure what are you talking about, ctrl/tab works fine at my end with a DG in one of the tabs, something else might be causing that!

Comment: @SamTheDev I am using empty 4.7.2 project running on Windows 10 machine, with nothing else but XAML code included in the question (pasted as the Window content), what is your setup?

Comment: Same I guess, just pasted your code, three tabs where the third one is the one with the grid, .net 4.7.2 on a win 10 1903.

Comment: @SamTheDev try putting the grid in second tab. The cycle stops/restarts at first grid encountered - if the grid is in the last tab you would not be able to tell if it stopped there or the cycle completed as normal.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, now I see the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a focus problem, when the `Datagrid` gets the focus it's lost from the `TabControl`, so set that focus programmatically whenever the ctrl/tab is pressed where the `DataGrid` is:

```
 <TabControl  x:Name="TabCtrl">
        <TabItem Header="Tab1" x:Name="Tab1" >
            <TextBox/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab3" x:Name="Tab2"  PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown">
            <TabItem.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="Items" Type="{x:Type Run}">
                    <Run Text="Foo"/>
                    <Run Text="Bar"/>
                    <Run Text="Baz"/>
                </x:Array>
            </TabItem.Resources>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{StaticResource Items}" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2"  x:Name="Tab3">
            <TextBox/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

The handler:

```
 private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab &&
            (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control && sender is TabItem)
        {
            TabCtrl.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good, I will be a bit more restrictive (check if there are any focus scopes in between source and sender) but it looks like it is the root of the problem. As a plus this can be easily made into attached behaviour and fixed on all TabControls by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
IsTabStop="False"
```

on your controls.  This prevents focus into that control?  A user could still manually click on the grid for focus (or other control), but without, it will ignore trying to get focus to that control.

Just to expand on the IsTabStop, you may want to try wrapping it into a user control and stop at the user control so it does not go into anything WITHIN it... such as

```
<UserControl IsTabStop="false">
   <DataGrid>
      …
   </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it in the question. I have tried it and `IsTabStop="False"` (along with several of KeyboardNavigation.XXX=YYY combinations) on the `DataGrid` has no effect. Setting it on every single control is undesirable (Tab without control should work within TabItems), but trying that regardless makes it act even wierder: the new order is *Tab1 > Tab2 > Tab1 > Tab2 > Tab3*.

Comment: @wondra, see revision, try wrapping into user control?

Comment: Alas no change what so ever. Moreover, even if it worked initially, I dont think it would still not function correctly if DataGrid was ever interacted with mouse, would it?